# WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, web-deployment, startup, wildfly-10

When I start Wildfly 10.1.0 I get *WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource* error. I get the error both if I start the server from Eclipse and from dos console. Detailed log messages:

```
09:55:44,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
09:55:47,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Bread.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Bread.war.dodeploy
09:55:47,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Butter.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Butter.war.dodeploy
09:55:47,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Jelly.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Jelly.war.dodeploy
09:55:47,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Eggs.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Eggs.war.dodeploy
09:55:47,539 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Jelly.war")]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"Jelly.war\")]"
09:55:47,543 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

What I do at this point is going into `C:\ApplicationServer\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments` folder and delete `Jelly.war.failed` file. I start the server again and at this point it starts normally.

The only difference between Jelly.war and the other apps is that in Eclipse, if I right click on the server in Servers tab and click on Add and Remove, it shows Jelly.war as a resource configured on the server. So the questions are: why does this error happen? How to solve it permanently? How not to make it happen again?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's wrong, but basically something is trying to add the `Jelly.war` deployment twice.